# Scrolling function called simultaneously while rotating the ipad screen

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am creating a UIscroll view with 8 pages. Each page is another view controller class with some functionality which is added to this scrollview.

On loading the app, when I scroll the screens from one page to another,the app just works fine.
But when I rotate the ipad to a different interface orientation, the UIScrollView delegate method - ScrollViewDidScroll is called upon and the current screen(page) is scrolled to the previous screen. Debugging makes me reckon that the scrolling function is called simultaneously with the device rotation.

How to stop/prevent the 'ScrollViewDidScroll' delegate method to be called on rotation so that only the rotation functionality is performed (i.e. the screen shouldn't be moved to previous one)?

I have tried different solutions provided but with little help

I am fairly new to xcode development.

Comment: @zombie007 Did you get any solution to this? I am facing the same issue..

Comment: @neeraj After probing in a lot to find a (decent)solution, I instead came up with a workaround - I created a global variable for maintaining the page number. When the scrolling method was done executing(post rotation), I set up the scrollview offset w.r.t the offset of the desired page. This page number was obtained from my global variable.

Comment: @zombie007 Actually I found a better solution. In the `setContentOffset:` method, iOS is actually changing the origin of the `bounds` property of the scrollView. So I just added a category for UIScrollView, in which a method named, say, `customSetContentOffset:` will set the origin of `scrollView.bounds` as the desired content offset. This won't make any callbacks, and of course, change the content offset.

Comment: @neeraj Your solution sounds a good implementation though I haven't tried it myself. Was this with which you overcame your issue


P.S: Excuse my late replies as I'm not a frequent visitor to this site.

Comment: Once you implement, you'll realize that its nothing. save old bounds in a variable, change the origin of this variable to desired content offset, then assign this variable to the bounds property of scroll view. Of course it can be added as a separate method, but adding it to a category comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scrollViewDidScroll` method to set the current page, you can use the `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method which is not called on rotation.

With this, you just have to set right `contentOffset` after the rotation, based on the current page.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm actually setting my global variable in the ScrollViewDidEndDecelerating method itself. So it worked. Thanks anyways :)